# react-native-pie: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "ARTShape" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm new to react native, and am tring to create a doughnut chart using react-native-pie but when i install and import the package, it says this error:

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "ARTShape" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
    in ARTShape (created by Shape)
    in Shape (created by ArcShape)
    in ArcShape (created by Sections)
    in Sections (created by Pie)
    in ARTGroup (created by Group)
    in Group (created by Pie)
    in ARTSurfaceView (created by Surface)
    in Surface (created by Pie)
    in Pie (created by SpendingHabits)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SpendingHabits)
    in SpendingHabits (created by Home)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Home)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Home)
    in RNCSafeAreaView
    in Unknown (created by Home)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Home)
    in Home (created by Index)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Index)
    in Index (created by App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by App)
    in ThemeProvider (created by Provider)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Portal.Host)
    in Portal.Host (created by Provider)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by Provider)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:95:17 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ReactFiberErrorDialog.js:52:19 in showErrorDialog
at App.js:56:21 in prepare
```

Also, my code editor is giving out this warning in the import statement:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-pie'. '/node_modules/react-native-pie/src/Pie.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-native-pie` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-native-pie';`
```

```
import Pie from "react-native-pie";
```

Since it is a blank expo project, i couldn't do pod install which seemed to be working for this error.